# Generating a random number in C++ including a negative range

Tags: c++

I've found many posts on how to generate a random number between, say, 1 and 10 in C++, but I am struggling to find a way to do so when negative numbers are included. I am trying to get a random number generated in the range [-1,1) but I can't find a good example that includes negatives.

Comment: how are you trying to do it? (code)

Comment: http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/random/uniform_real_distribution/uniform_real_distribution/

Comment: Just generate a random number between 0 and 2 and subtract 1 from it.

Comment: I 2nd PeterSW comment, but this is the better reference: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/random/uniform_real_distribution

Answer (score 5):

If you're talking about real numbers, use `std::uniform_real_distribution`:

```
std::default_random_engine generator(
        std::chrono::system_clock::now().time_since_epoch().count());
std::uniform_real_distribution<double> distribution(-1.0, 1.0);
std::cout << distribution(generator) << std::endl;
```

Be sure to include `<random>`. Here's a [live example](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/803b63aa877f8852).

If you're limited to `rand()`, this is about the best you can do:

```
srand(static_cast<unsigned int>(time(NULL)));
double x = -1. + rand() / (RAND_MAX / 2.);
std::cout << x << std::endl;
```

Be sure to include `<cstdlib>` or `<stdlib.h>`. Here's another [live example](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/6f60aa3409404e7b). Be warned though, the `<random>` header is preferred over `rand()`. See this presentation for why [rand() is considered harmful](https://channel9.msdn.com/Events/GoingNative/2013/rand-Considered-Harmful) for more information.

Comment: Unfortunately I am limited to using rand(). Is there any way to do it with that?